# CropperJS creating new images on page instead of cropping the specified image

Tags: javascript, cropperjs

Using cropper js to attempt to crop an img on the page, however,
it's actually appending 2 more of the same images on the page that I can "scroll" to change their aspect ratio.

```
            const cropper = new Cropper(image, {
                aspectRatio: 16 / 9,
                crop(event) {
                    console.log(event.detail.x);
                    console.log(event.detail.y);
                    console.log(event.detail.width);
                    console.log(event.detail.height);
                    console.log(event.detail.rotate);
                    console.log(event.detail.scaleX);
                    console.log(event.detail.scaleY);
                }
});
```

I also tried to do this to set the crop sizes;

```
       viewMode: 1,
        setData() {
            x: dimensions.left;
            y: dimensions.top;
            width: dimensions.width;
            height: dimensions.height;
        }
```

However, it's proving to be difficult. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Switched to using the Jimp library. Was much easier to figure out how to crop using that.